# Get count CHAT message

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, chat, message

I want get count chat messages between me and my friend (between two people). I would like use php apy.
It will somehow find the number of CHAT messages between us ?

### Thanks..

edit: Thank you luca. It is found! And I would like messages count cut to half so How many send messages me and how many send messages my friend. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can look at FQL Thread table 
see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/thread/ 
field message_count

Comment: Wow, I had forgotten that chat messages are stored in the normal messages location.  +1 for the reminder.  :)

Comment: Now i knowing count all message together in table thread -- message_count. 
I find  thread_id in table thread And use thread_id in table message.
But fql writen only 50 last message so I can not filtre who send message. I would like know How many messages send I and how many messages send my friend.

Answer (score 3):

TRY THIS FQL:

```
SELECT viewer_id,recipients,message_count FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 ORDER BY message_count DESC
```

Comment: No point answering after two years unless the answer is adding more value and providing more explanation.